# What kind of errors are these? I'm having linux error even though I'm not working on linux

Tags: c++, c, error-handling, compiler-errors

I was working on online compiler and this error occured. Can someone tell me what kind of errors these are and what's causing them?

```
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 11
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 1 has invalid symbol index 12
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 2 has invalid symbol index 2
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 3 has invalid symbol index 2
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 4 has invalid symbol index 11
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 5 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 6 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 7 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 8 has invalid symbol index 12
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 9 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 10 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 11 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 12 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 13 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 14 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 15 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 16 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 17 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 18 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 19 has invalid symbol index 21
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_line): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 2
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
```

Comment: An online compiler compiles your code on it's server, not on your computer. And obviously this particular server you are using is a Linux one. No idea what the error means, it might help if you shared the code that caused the error.

Comment: Maybe it is a blessing in disguise that the server is having these issues.  Now you have to actually get yourself a compiler, install it locally, and use that to learn C++.

Answer (score 2):

The online compiler has its servers running linux that execute your code. Hence, the Linux errors. We could help you debug the errors if you write your code.

Answer (score 1):

That error generally happens when the *main* function is not defined

Do you have a message like

> undefined reference to `main'

after the messages you give ?

If yes just define *main* which is the entry point of the program

```
int main() // probably you do not need the arguments
{
   ...some code
}
```